# How to store JSON.(discord.py)

Tags: discord.py

So I tried storing a variable to a json file,but it gives me this error:

*Object of type Command is not JSON serializable*

The code something like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
num = 0

def store():
    with open("num.json", 'w') as file:
       json.dump(num, file)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()

async def increase():
  num += 1
  await ctx.send("I increased your number,now it is: " + num)
  store()
```

Comment: I see 2 problems there and neither matches your exception. Post the full traceback and the actual code.

Comment: Hey have you actually learnt json before?

Answer (score 1):

*Object of type Command is not JSON serializable* says, that variable (or entity) you provided can't be transformed (serialized) into the JSON format.

In your case that is because you haven't follow `key:value` json rule. JSON is similar to the Python's dict (except keys can only be strings). So to be able to store your variable, you have to pass it to the `json.dump` function as following: `{"my_var": num}`.

So simply change your code to something like that:

```py
def store():
    with open("num.json", 'w') as file:
       json.dump({"num": num}, file) #HERE'S THE DEAL! ENTITY SHOULD BE DICT!

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()

async def increase():
  num += 1
  await ctx.send("I increased your number,now it is: " + num)
  store()
```

Answer (score 0):

You didnt open the json file, so you cant write to it.

try this:

```py
num = 0
@bot.command()
async def increase():
    num += 1
    #opening the json
    with open("num.json", "r") as file:
        x = json.load(file)
    #setting the number
    x["num"] = num
    #now store it
    with open("num.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(file, x, indent=4)
    await ctx.send("I increased your number,now it is: " + num)
```

the num.json should like this (before running the command):

```json
{
    "num": 0
}
```